# org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: A shuffle map stage with indeterminate output was failed and retried

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, delta-lake

while writing spark (13.3) Dataframe to deltaTable i am running into an error -

```
org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: A shuffle map stage with indeterminate output was failed and retried. However, Spark cannot rollback the ResultStage 1607 to re-process the input data, and has to fail this job. Please eliminate the indeterminacy by checkpointing the RDD before repartition and try again.
```

I know for sure, if I replace the NULLs with empty string this job runs fine and dataframe is saved to the DeltaTable without any issue

```
df.fillna('')
```

but if I dont perform the fillna('') on the dataframe, it errors out with the above error. I want to keep the NULLs instead as I am syncing the deltaTable data to the DynamoDB at a later stage in the solution. It will be easier to keep the NULLs and skip these attributes copying to DynamoDB instead of creating Attributes with Empty string on the DynamoDB
I have seen the similar error was addressed in other posts but I have not seen the error with reason. thats why posting it again